# What are the best practices when there are many css links in the HTML5 page?

Tags: css, frontend

have several css's in my HTML5, each css is for a different thing, such as a css for a button type, a css for a specific effect ...

What should I do to "pack" all these css's?

**Example:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/fonts/_font-icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/fonts/_font-trebuchet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/fonts/_font-verdana.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/utilities/_colors.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/utilities/buttons/shapes/_circle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/utilities/buttons/types/_switch-indicator.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/utilities/_sizing.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/components/partials/cards/charts/main/_main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/components/partials/cards/charts/secondary/_sales.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/effects/_no-select.css">
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of / used any build automation tools using Node.js? A task such as this is very easy to setup using the likes of https://gulpjs.com/ and https://github.com/mariocasciaro/gulp-concat-css ... I would definitely recommend spending some time using gulp as it will make your web dev life a lot easier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't improve the load time, but if you just don't want to have so many link tags, you can link only one css file and use [@import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) to import the other files.

main.css (place inside */css/*)

```
@import 'fonts/_font-icons.css';
@import 'fonts/_font-verdana.css';
@import 'fonts/_font-trebuchet.css';
@import 'utilities/_colors.css';
@import 'utilities/buttons/shapes/_circle.css';
@import 'utilities/buttons/types/_switch-indicator.css';
@import 'utilities/_sizing.css';
@import 'components/partials/cards/charts/main/_main.css';
@import 'components/partials/cards/charts/secondary/_sales.css';
@import 'effects/_no-select.css';
```

And then in the html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

If possible, I would recommend using [sass](https://sass-lang.com/), and compiling all of those files into one.

Comment: muito obrigado, SaS é apenas um pré-compilador né? Eu utilizei o mesmo jeito de separação dos .css do sass, mas irei utiliza-lo.